# how to escape normal characters in regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

I'm running the latest version of sinatra and ruby 1.9.3

I let users create a custom regex in my sinatra app.

code:

```
Posts.all(:message => %r{(?i)(.*)#{params[:searchterm]}(.*)})
```

How do I escape `#{params[:searchterm]}` so that the user can't insert more regex?

(if the user searches for `(.)*user` he get's results that shouldn't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) to escape the variable value:

```
%r{(?i)(.*)#{Regexp.escape(params[:searchterm])}(.*)}
```